# Creating a file with Cron

Tags: cron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Just for the sake of practicing I am trying to create a file with Cron every minute in every hour, in every day of the month, in every week, in every day of the week.

In WSL (latest) with Bash 4.4.20, each one of these commands didn't work after being saved in Cron via `crontab -e` (although each `touch` command itself works outside of crontab);

**command 1:**

```
* * * * * touch ~/example.example
```

**command 2:**

```
* * * * * touch ${HOME}/example.example
```

What may cause that problem?

Comment: By the way, as far as I know `touch` will not create copies of the same file in other names; i.e. the same file will always appear so I am not afraid of filling the storage device endlessly with this command.

Comment: The problem is WSL. WSL does not run daemons and was never intended to, and I believe cron is a daemon.

Comment: Did you start the cron service, e.g. with `sudo service cron start`? Works for me on WSL/Debian.

Comment: @Freddy thanks that was it ! Indeed, I didn't start the service up until reading your comment. I have recently started it and indeed the file has been started to be recursively created. I have double checked it and indeed the file is created.

Comment: So @Freddy if you make it answer I should accept it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

As user:Freddy pointed out in the comment section, what I lacked was starting the Cron service.

```
sudo service cron start
```

This helped. For some reason it wasn't started in my WSL automatically.

Both commands worked with this.